# Duplicating form sections

Tags: jquery, forms, clone, form-fields

Hoping someone could help me with this code snippet below. I'm trying to duplicate form fields on my site when a button is clicked.

The problem is, I'm having trouble making this work for multiple forms on the same html page. This is only working for the first form. When I try adding a second form, the button on the second form duplicates the first form within the second form. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

HTML

```
<div class="duplicate-sections">
 <div class="form-section">
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
        <input name="firstName[]" id="firstName" value="" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
        <input name="lastName[]" id="lastName" value="" type="text" />
      </p>
        <a href="#" class="remove">Remove Section</a>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="#" class="addsection">Add Section</a>
```

Jquery

```
//define template
var template = $('.duplicate-sections .form-section:first').clone();

//define counter
var sectionsCount = 1;

//add new section
$('body').on('click', '.addsection', function() {

    //increment
    sectionsCount++;

    //loop through each input
    var section = template.clone().find(':input').each(function(){

        //set id to store the updated section number
        var newId = this.id + sectionsCount;

        //update for label
        $(this).prev().attr('for', newId);

        //update id
        this.id = newId;

    }).end()

    //inject new section
    .appendTo('.duplicate-sections');
    return false;
});

//remove section
$('.duplicate-sections').on('click', '.remove', function() {
    //fade out section
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
        //remove parent element (main section)
        $(this).parent().parent().empty();
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqOPym)**.

You've to change this part in your `remove` action :

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function(){
    //remove parent element (main section)
    $(this).parent().parent().empty();
    return false;
});
```

To be :

```
$(this).closest('.form-section').fadeOut(300, function(){
    $(this).closest('.form-section').empty();
});
```

Using the `closest()` function and specific class `form-section` to target the parent div. also you've to replace :

```
.appendTo('.duplicate-sections');
```

By :

```
.appendTo($(this).prev('.duplicate-sections'));
```

Since if you leave you slector with just a class `duplicate-sections` the new form will be appended to all the elements with this class, you have to specify the one related with the clicked href `Add Section`.

Last thing to do is adding an extra attribute `data-section` in every add section link to specify the number of the form (0 based) :

```
<a href="#" class="addsection" data-section='0'>Add Section</a>
```

Then store all the forms in an array :

```
var forms = [];

$('.duplicate-sections .form-section').each(function(){
  forms.push($(this).clone());                
})
```

And get the related form with clicked link using :

```
var template = forms[$(this).data('section')];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. I've created a codepen with the fix you've provided, but there still seems to be an issue with the forms duplicating. incorrectly. Please see this link: http://codepen.io/EBM84/pen/oYjGzY

Comment: I'm assuming this would mean perhaps changing the class .duplicate-sections to a specific ID per each form? If I go that route, would I then have to duplicate the same Jquery code for each form?

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use the current edit. I'm just trying to understand this part of your comment "Since if you leave you slector with just a class duplicate-sections the new form will be appended to all the elements with this class, you have to specify the one related with the clicked href Add Section." I am just trying to understand that portion so form 1 does not duplicate under form 2 when I hit form 2's button.

Comment: I'm sorry i've just noticed that the first form cloned in the both sections, check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qqOPym), i've fixed that by using an extra attribute `data-section` in every `add section` link to specify the number of the form

Comment: Great! This seems to be working. Would this also work if I added more forms to the page?